# datacacheexception Cache referred to does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, appfabric, windows-server

I get the following error when I invoke the call factory.GetDefaultCache()...

**ErrorCode:SubStatus:Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the Cache administration tool to create a Cache.**

Please help.. thanks..

Here is my simple application:

```
var config = new Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
var servers = new List<Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheServerEndpoint>();
servers.Add(new Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheServerEndpoint("mymachine123", 22233));
config.Servers = servers;
var factory = new Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory(config);

////var factory = _cacheFactory;

var cache = factory.GetDefaultCache();  <---- *** Error happens here..***
var key = "mykey";
var obj = cache[key];
if (obj == null)
{
    cache[key] = "I am data for caching";
}
obj = cache[key];
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

When I run the command: start-cachecluster, I get the following:

HostName : CachePort      Service Name            Service Status Version Info
--------------------      ------------            -------------- ------------
mymachine123:22233         AppFabricCachingService UP             1 [1,1][1,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just set this up myself.. it may be a permissions issue.  Add the user that the caching service is running under via `Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount <youraccountname>`

Comment: My code worked the next day with out any changes.. I did not manually start the caching service.. but used the command start-cachecluster to start the service.. that could have made the difference but thank you for your answer any ways..

Comment: if the appfabric server is accessed by IIS then you have to give the permission to iis user(IIS_IUSRS) and if it is the production environment then you might have to give the permission to AppPool/YourApplicationPool_InIIs