# Azure cache configs - multiple on one storage account?

Tags: caching, azure, azure-storage

while developing Azure application I got famous error "Cache referred to does not exist", and after a while I found this solution: [datacacheexception Cache referred to does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262839/datacacheexception-cache-referred-to-does-not-exist) (for short: dont point multiple cache clusters to one storage account by ConfigStoreConnectionString)

Well, I have 3 roles using co-located cache, and testing+production environment. So I would have to create 6 "dummy" storage accounts just for cache configuration. This doesnt seems very nice to me.

So the question is - is there any way to point multiple cache clusters to one storage account? for example, specify different containers for them (they create one named "cacheclusterconfigs" by default) or so?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the three roles in a single cloud service? and are you trying to have each role have its own cache (aka co-locating a cache in each role)?

Comment: 2 cloud services (first have 1 web role with cache, second on have 1 web role and 1 worker role with cache), and yes, cache is co-located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your setup, i would point each cloud service at its own storage account. So this gives two per environment (one for each cloud service). Now there are other alternatives, you could set up Server AppFabric cache in an IaaS VM and expose that to both of your cloud services by placing them all within a single Azure Virtual Network. However, this will introduce latency to the connections as well as increase costs (from running the virtual network).

You can also put the storage account for cache as the same one used by diagnostics or the data storage for your cloud services, just be aware of any scalability limits as the cache will generate some traffic (mainly from the addition of new items to the cache).

But unfortunately, to my knowledge there's no option currently to allow for two caches to share the same storage account.